# Why doesn't the permutation formula work on questions regarding unique rearrangements of a specific word?

Tags: probability, permutations

I have not used probabilities for a long time. I have just went through a summary of probabilities, but still have some ambiguities, including when to use the Permutation (or Combination) formula and when not to use them.

For example, below is a question that I think the permutation formula should work on, but it doesn't!

*How many unique ways are there to rearrange the word "PRIOR"?*

- There are 5 slots (letters) in this word to be field, so it would be `5!`. However, 2 of the letters being R, makes some combinations the same, so we have to remove those *non-unique* answers. Therefore, we have to remove those two, so we divide the 5! by 2!.

Now, I think the permutation formula should be able to answer this question, but it produces a different result (`5!/3!`). What is my mistake here? Which part of the permutations I misunderstood?

Thanks!

Comment: What formula produces $\frac{5!}{3!}$?  $\frac{5!}{2!}$ is correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Are you thinking for some reason that $~_5P_2$ is the answer to the question of how many rearrangements of `PRIOR` there are?  No.  You need to stop and look at the definitions.  $~_nP_r~$ (*or as I prefer to write it, $n\frac{r}{~}$*) counts the number of ways you can order $r$ non-repeating elements from $n$ distinct elements.  Equivalently, the number of injective functions from $[r]$ to $[n]$.  The number of rearrangements of `PRIOR` is instead perhaps better described as the multinomial coefficient $\binom{5}{2,1,1,1}$

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for the information! I thought I am following the correct notation, sorry about that! I was thinking about this formula: $_5 P_2$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks! Can you please elaborate on your last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

In order to count the total number of ways there are to rearrange the letters of the word $PRIOR$, here is what I would do:

Although the letter $R$ is duplicated, count the number of ways there are to rearrange the letters assuming that all the letters are different (I will use $R_0$ and $R_1$ to highlight this). There are $5!$ different ways of doing it. One possible setting could be $$IR_0OPR_1.$$
Now, since $R_0$ and $R_1$ are different letters (but they represent the same symbol $R$), divide by the total number of ways to rearrange the 2-letters-word $R_0R_1$. It can be done in $2!$ different ways. Then the final answer should be $$\dfrac{5!}{2!}.$$
If the original word were $$TOMATOMATO,$$ where the letters $T$ and $O$ appear $3$ times, and the remaining $M$ and $A$ appear twice each, by applying this 'algorithm' we will have that a feasible setting could be $$M_0M_1O_0T_0A_0A_1T_1T_2O_1O_2.$$ This will lead us to a total of $$\dfrac{10!}{2!\cdot 2!\cdot 3!\cdot 3!}$$
different ways of rearranging the word $TOMATOMATO$.

From here, it shouldn´t be hard to obtain a general expression for any word.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is indeed a very interesting way for thinking about this question. One will never forget it, and it really makes answering rearrangement questions simple. However, I think it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You say you don't understand why the permutation formula *wouldn't* work, but it would help us answer your question if you clarify why you think it *should* work. The permutation formula is for a specific type of rearrangement of $k$ distinct letters chosen out of $n$ distinct letters, and doesn't apply when there are repeats unless it's appropriately modified. Or put another way: not every problem involving permutations (colloquial definition) can be directly solved using permutations ($_n P_r$ definition).

**Edit responding to OP's comment:** The fact that $_5P_3$ (*not $_5P_2$*) happens to give the same answer as the number of rearrangements of PRIOR is more like a coincidence than it is a generally applicable formula.

It comes from one of them being written as $_5 P_3 = \frac{5!}{2!}$ and the PRIOR rearrangements as $\frac{5!}{2! 1! 1! 1!}$.

If there's exactly one repeated letter that occurs $r > 1$ times in a word of $n$ otherwise distinct letters, then $_n P_{n - r} = \frac{n!}{r!}$ will happen to equal the number of possible rearrangements of that word, but if there's multiple repeats, you need extra factorials in the denominator that $_n P_r$ can't always accomplish.
For instance, the number of ways to rearrange the letters in AURORA, which has 2 A's, 1 U, 2 R's, and 1 O,  is $$\frac{6!}{2!1!2!1!} = 180,$$ and there's no way to write $180$ in the form $_nP_r$ aside from the trivial $n = 180$, $r = 1$.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem! I didn't think of these two as two different problems. What you mentioned was helpful.

Comment: So, going back to your last sentence, can we say that 'only those permutation problems can be solved using the $_5P_2$ formula that does not involve repeats'? But then, shouldn't we be able to use the formula if we consider both Rs in `PRIOR` a single one? Or I am still missing something here?

Comment: @RFNO My response got too long for a comment, so I edited my answer instead. Hope that helps!